# Specifications of Thorntail project-defaults.yml

Tags: wildfly-swarm, thorntail

I found example at [Thorntail Documentation v2.0.0](http://docs.wildfly-swarm.io/2.0.0.Final/#_example_full_project_defaults_yml_file), but I think Thorntail will have more setting items, actually.

Where are specifications of `project-defaults.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not Thorntail-core's setting, but fraction's one.
Thus you should refer each faraction's doc.

For example, Datasource setting items are defined at [Datasources fraction](https://docs.thorntail.io/2.4.0.Final/#_datasources).
There are items `swarm.datasources.data-sources.KEY.allocation-retry` and so on.